# Is there a Linux utility that can clear Word Document properties?

Tags: linux, microsoft-word, properties

Is there a Linux utility that can clear Word Document properties?

I want to keep the doc file. These are the properties that Word auto fills and I'd like them removed:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using aspose for that, we already had a licence.

Answer (score 2):

You could use OpenOffice.org Writer . You can find more details [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/office_guides/openoffice_writer_user_guide/openoffice_guide_Using_document_properties_to_hold_information_that_changes.html)

or else have a look at [wvware](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking. You could just open the doc in OpenOffice, then Save As a native OO document (which would remove any M$ Word-specific properties.)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are looking to batch clean these files, you could just `copy+paste the text into any other document editing program`. I assume you are stripping the meta-data, not formatting.